# How to calculate Max Drawdown Percentage?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Can anybody help me calculate "Max Strategy Drawdown %" as shown in the strategy testor.

**TV mentions the formula for Drawdown dollar value:**

> "Highest Equity of all time - Lowest Equity after the highest peak"

**While Percentage Drawdown is calculated relatively:**

> The percentage and absolute values of a drawdown are two different
> metrics. They are tracked independently. For example, let’s say the
> initial capital is $100. After a series of losing trades, equity
> decreases to $50. The drawdown amounts to $50 in absolute terms and
> 50% in relative terms. Later, after a series of profitable trades,
> equity increases to $300 and then drops to $200. In this case, the
> absolute drawdown will be $100, and the relative drawdown, 33%. The
> overall maximum absolute drawdown of the strategy will be $100, and
> the maximum relative drawdown will be 50%.

```
//@version=5
strategy("Max Drawdown")

maxDrawdown = (strategy.max_drawdown/strategy.initial_capital * 100) 

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be fairly simple depending on what exactly you need.
Pine Script helps you a lot with that. [Link](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dclosedtrades%7Bdot%7Dmax_drawdown)

> ```
> maxTradeDrawDown() =>
> maxDrawdown = 0.0
> for tradeNo = 0 to strategy.closedtrades - 1
>     maxDrawdown := math.max(maxDrawdown, strategy.closedtrades.max_drawdown(tradeNo))
> result = maxDrawdown
> ```

Like the example from TradingView shows you can use the built-in `strategy.closedtrades.max_drawdown(trade_num)`. Depending on your needs you can get the max drawdown (like above) or without `math.max()` you can add up to a total drawdown, whatever you want. Then you can calculate your percentage by deviding it by your `strategy.initial_capital`.

Comment: Actually this calculates the max drawdown value of a trade out of all the trades.
I am however looking for "Strategy Max Drawdown %".
Though the dollar value can be pulled easily by `strategy.max_drawdown`, but dividing it by `strategy.intial_capital` does not give the correct percentage because it only calculates the **absolute** percentage, not **relative** percentage. 
I have mentioned tradingview percentage calculation method in my original post, if it makes any sense.

Comment: Yeah I know, sorry if my answer was not precise enough. I was to provide you a general example how the "strategy.closedtrades.max_drawdown(trade_num)" can be used to calculate everything you want. It is the function you need. For your case you'll need to evaluate your drawdown per closed strategy (by the provided function) and store the results like "var maxDrawDownSoFar = float(na)" that you can evaluate at the end yourself, also using the formula from tradingview.